# moc_ files broken while importing a Qt project from another machine?

Tags: c++, qt

I downloaded a Qt project but when I want to compile it, it gives the following error on "release" mode:

> moc_mainwindow.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to 'MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()' moc_adminpage.cpp:-1: error:
>   undefined reference to 'AdminPage::on_pushButton_clicked()'

And doesn't compile at all

On "debug" mode however it does compile and the exe runs BUT then it gives the following warning:

> QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_pushButton_clicked()
>   QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_lineEdit_editingFinished()

And the noted "pushButton" does not do anything when it's clicked!

So I know a little about moc files, but I have never had to actually do anything with them. I'm guessing there is something wrong with them though. It looks like Qt cannot connect my `on_pushButton_clicked()` function (slot) to pushButton clicked signal.

PS 1: The errors noted in the "release" part take place in the moc files.

PS 2: In each of my moc files on the first line there is an `#include "../../FinalProject/mainwindow.h`
which causes the following warning

> no such file o directory

This probably must be it, but how can I fix it ?

Comment: Are you using qmake as your build system? Did you also download the moc_* files? Have you tried deleting them and let qmake regenerate them?

Comment: @NikosC. : yes im using qmake . i tried deleting them . it throws another error at me saying cant find the moc files .

Comment: Please show the command you're using to build the project, including the call to qmake.

Comment: have you tried deleting all "Makefile" files in your build directory?

Answer (score 0):

The errors are caused because you have defined the slots `on_pushButton_clicked()` and `on_lineEdit_editingFinished()` but you have not used its. 
Check your `mainwindow.h` and delete these slots from `private slots:` section.